# Multibranch Pipeline job configuration with logrotator using DSL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, multibranch-pipeline

I'm using jenkins job dsl to configure my multibranch pipeline jobs. Actually my all settings are working except logRotator. My aim is to delete the old builds and keep a particular number of build. I can use

```
options {

    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10'))
  }
```

in freestyle job for this purpose. The multibranch pipeline job configure section not having discardold build section as an option in UI. Is there any way I can use the logRotator without adding this to my jenkins file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the following section in my code to implement the buildDiscarder functionality in multibranch pipeline jobs.

```
 multibranchPipelineJob("job") {
  branchSources {
  branchSource {
    source {
      bitbucket {
        credentialsId("myid")
        repoOwner("iam")
        repository("job")                       
 traits {
          headWildcardFilter {
            includes("branchestoinclude")
            excludes("toexclude")
          }
        }
      }
    }
    strategy {
      defaultBranchPropertyStrategy {
        props {
          buildRetentionBranchProperty {
            buildDiscarder {
              logRotator {
                daysToKeepStr("-1")
                numToKeepStr("8")
                artifactDaysToKeepStr("-1")
                artifactNumToKeepStr("-1")
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `strategy` doesn't seem to be available - perhaps in newer versions! I get error using this

Comment: artifactDaysToKeepStr("-1")
artifactNumToKeepStr("-1")     what does this -1 mean actually

Answer (score -1):

In Jenkins job dsl, the multibranchPipelineJob has an option to add the following lines for discarding old builds.

```
orphanedItemStrategy {
            discardOldItems { numToKeep(10) }
        }
```

Comment: I'm having this section in my code. But orphanedItemStrategy won't give the build Discarder functionality.